# Сложный запрос PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

Есть таблица `posts`, в ней поля `id`, `title`, `body`, `author_id`

Нужно вытащить из неё ТОЛЬКО те `author_id` которым соответствует только одна запись (новички, у которых только один пост). Можно это как-то сделать одним запросом? Или, если проще - получить только количество таких авторов.

`PostgreSQL 9.5`

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683942/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D1%83-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B9-mongodb я просто оставлю это здесь

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select author_id, count(id) 
from posts
group by author_id
having count(id)  = 1
```

Запрос совершенно не сложный, если знать азы SQL

Comment: Благодарю! Знал 11 лет назад, с тех пор не приходилось этим заниматься, забылось. Работает, спасибо