# Выбор по количеству записей MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

Я сегодня уже [спрашивал](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/683805/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-postgresql) по поводу PostgreSQL, теперь нужно сделать примерно то же самое, но для MongoDB.

Есть коллекция из полумиллиона документов. 1 документ = 1 посещение сайта человеком, лог своего рода. Поле `cookies.PHPSESSID` содержит id сессии. Нужно из этой коллекции выбрать тех, кто посетил не менее 6 страниц сайта. То есть задача очень похожа на ту, ссылку на которую привёл выше, но для Mongo.

Пробовал так:

```
db.activity_log.aggregate([{ 
    $group: { 
        _id: "cookies.PHPSESSID",
        count: { 
            $sum: 1 
        } 
    } 
}])
```

Но к ожидаемым результатам это не привело. `cookies.PHPSESSID` выбиралось нормально, а вот по какому принципу формировался count - для меня до сих пор загадка. Ну и да, выбирались не те PHPSESSID, которым соответствует минимум 6 документов, а любые фиг пойми какие, и те и другие.

Comment: Блин... это меня переклинило - перепутал MongoDB и MariaDB. Приношу свои извинения...

Comment: как в итоге сделать-то блин..)

Comment: Ну чисто навскидку будет что-то типа `db.cookies.aggregate([{ $group: { _id: "$PHPSESSID", count: { $sum: 1 } } }]).find({$count: {$gt: 5}})`.

Comment: @Akina `TypeError: db.user_activity.aggregate(...).find is not a function :
@(shell):1:1` я так понял, что по результату, который возвращает `aggregate()`, нельзя выполнить `.find()`. хотя если он возвращает некую условно коллекцию, то непонятно почему нельзя. То что Вы указали до `.find()` я тоже пробовал) результат был не тот, которого хотелось.

Comment: Ну то, что я указал, можно считать максимум приблизительным направлением размышлений, не более. Да и то не факт, что правильным.